# code signing with vb6

Tags: api, vb6, sign

How do I sign my vb6 code?

What api do I use?

I heard CAPICOM is no longer supported in Vista upwards.  I'm developing with vb6 and need this to work on win2000 upwards.

Comment: The part that's missing is "I purchased a certificate and they told me to do this and that".  Who did you get it from?

Comment: what i meant is that i want top sign my code so that before it runs on any system, windows check the signature, and if it has been tampered with, the app will refuse to run. also the code signing will allow user verify that the application is truly from me, because my signature is there

Comment: Yes, that's what signing does.  Here's a KB article from Verisign, the kind of company from which you can buy the certificate: https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=AR190&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm shelling [signtool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28VS.80%29.aspx) to do the job, something like this

```
c:>signtool.exe sign /f KeyFile.p12 /d "App description" MyApp.exe
```

It does requires CAPICOM 2.0 being installed.

Comment: it require CAPICOM to be installed in development environment or consumer environment ??

Comment: You run signtool as part of your build and package process.  It needs CAPICOM at that point but I don't see any reason why you'd need to deploy CAPICOM as part of your application.

Comment: what about certificates, how do i create it

Answer (score 0):

[Introducing CAPICOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995332.aspx)

> [CAPICOM is a 32-bit only component that is available for use in the following operating systems: Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows XP, and Windows 2000. Instead, use the .NET Framework to implement security features. For more information, see Alternatives to Using CAPICOM.]

So though CAPICOM is "deprecated" what that really means is "we want you to move to .Net" instead.

I just retested a program using a few CAPICOM functions in Win7, works fine.

Comment: I recall that CAPICOM was a way to call the MS Crypto API from VB6 using COM, not a code signing technology.

Comment: Interesting, just checked the CAPICOM page on MSDN and it does allow for digital signatures. Never knew that.

Comment: @Smith: Article here if you're curious http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx